# Preventing Keyboard Covering TextBox

Tags: c#, keyboard, uwp, uielement

I have a page that holds a small text box, an image, then a larger text box. When I load an image & type in the textbox, the keyboard covers the text box. Any ideas on what code fixes it & where to place the code to fix it? I tried to using the.

```
<TextBox PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="true"/>
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do in your solution is to prevent keyboard display when the focus is set programmatically to that TextBox. Since previously you said that you type in the TextBox when the keyboard appears (so you are setting the focus *not* programmatically, but by user interaction), it seems to me that it's a solution for an entirely different problem.

What I think you need is described in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185611.aspx) article.
In a nutshell: you have to subscribe to the Showing and Hiding events of the [InputPane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx) associated with your application window, and arrange your UI so the important controls stay on the screen even when the touch keyboard becomes visible. Also, don't forget to take care of the EnsuredFocusedElementInView property on the event arguments.